# Retrieve SharePoint tenant url using Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint-online, multi-tenancy, microsoft-graph

I have developed an MVC application enabled single sign on with Office 365. 
I want retrieve SharePoint tenant URL after logged in.

**Example:** Suppose I have logged in with `user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com`. I can build the SharePoint tenant URL with by taking `contoso` name from the user principal and building the URL like `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com`.
This is working fine however if multi domain exist in single tenant I am unable to retrieve the URL when other domain user logged in

**Example:** If `user1@domain2.onmicrosoft.com` my SharePoint tenant URL building like `https://domain2-admin.sharepoint.com` but SharePoint tenant url same like `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use this to get a list of domains and use IsDefault field to identify if it is a default/primary domain:  https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/domains

Answer (score 0):

Use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root` endpoint. Look for `webUrl` property.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to achieve the exact same thing (had to compile the scope for getting a SPO token, but the name of the scope needs to include the SPO site URL). I was able to get it following @GiedriusL's advice to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root with an MS Graph OAuth token. Worked as a charm

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/123463)